# Searching for FTP over SSH (not SFTP) Server and Java library

Tags: java, ftp, sftp

As a requirement in a customer project is to support FTP over SSH I'm currently looking for 2 things:

1. A SecureFTP-Server for testing purpose

2. A Java library which supports FTP over SSH.

When searching for a solution the main problem is that ALL implementations are also transfering the files encrypted (and therefore implementing SSH FTP) - this is NOT what I'm looking for. As described here (http://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_File_Transfer_Protocol - german only) only the authentication and file listing should be encrypted - the file transfer itself is not encrypted.

Please don't try to convince me to use SSH FTP (or other secure protocolls like FTPS) - I need to use the more insecure version as the customer uses it...

EDIT: [FTP over SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_FTP#FTP_over_SSH_.28not_SFTP.29) exactly describs what I'm searching for.

Comment: You have mixed different inapplicable things in your question (there's no such protocol as "SecureFTP", neither there's SSH FTP), so I am gladly voting to close the question as not a question.

Comment: Interesting. Is that the same thing as [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_FTP#FTP_over_SSH_.28not_SFTP.29)? @Eugene: There seems to be *something* of that kind, but until today I've never heard of it (it looks very much that it's just a hacked-together SSH port forward of the control connection, with plain ol'FTP doing the data transfer).

Comment: @Eugene: Thanks for the answer - nevertheless I kindly ask you to have a look at the wiki-page I've mentioned above and/or http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SSH_File_Transfer_Protocol . In case I mixed some protocol names I'm sorry for this and of course feel free to vote for closing - nevertheless the need for a solution for the described situation still exists (even if protocol names may be not used correctly)

Comment: @Piskvor Exactly, RFC_959_FTP_over_SSH is possible, but to certain extent tricky and hard to configure, so I have yet to see a single real-world implementation of it.

Comment: @dpr there exist three different things: (a) SSH File Transfer Protocol, (b) FTP over SSL and (c, not a real world case) FTP over SSH (i.e. with SSH tunneling). Please define what you need and update your question by editing it.

Comment: @Eugene: I've added additional information in my post - FTP over SSH is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

If FTP over SSH is what you're after, one of the projects mentioned at the Wikipedia page on [FTP over SSH](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Secure_FTP#FTP_over_SSH_.28not_SFTP.29) is [FONC](http://fonc.sourceforge.net/), which is both a client and a server, written in Java, and licensed under GPLv2.

This looks like what you're looking for, check if the license is applicable to your project.